# How to display an image in a Thunderbird column?

Tags: thunderbird

The Thunderbird Addon [Display Contact Photo](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/display-contact-photo/) shows a nice picture of users (or optionally their [gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/)/identicon/wavatar/monsterid) next to the mail header and in the recepient list. Is it possible to have that icon also displayed in the Recepient column (or even better, the Correspondent one from [Show InOut](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/show-inout/)) or a separate column in the default mail list?

That is, I'd like to have the image from the left of the contacts in this screenshot

[image]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.net](https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/previews/full/59/59132.png?modified=1321995412))</sub>

also in the email overview so I can see very quickly whom each email is from.

Answer (score 1):

[Thunderbayes++](https://code.google.com/p/thunderbayes/) shows an icon in the email overview, if a mail is spam, ham or unsure. Maybe the code of this extension can help you to implement this.